# How to insert existing DataBase in Android Project

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-database

I would like to insert an existing SQLite database into my Android project.

In other words, I do not want to create it, but just to be able to access it within my app.

How would I be able to access the database, and in which folder should I put it?

Comment: Put in assets folder in your app. check this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9109438/how-to-use-an-existing-database-with-an-android-application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it's pretty easy, just put your database.db in assets folder and you can use [Android SQLiteAssetHelper](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper) to read and write the database, this library makes the process pretty easy and straightforward.

Import the library

```
compile 'com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset:sqliteassethelper:+'
```

and then

```
public class MyDatabase extends SQLiteAssetHelper {

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "northwind.db";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

public MyDatabase(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);

}
```

That's all you need to do to access the database.

[Here](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper/tree/master/samples/database-v1/src/main/java/com/example) is the full example for your convenience.

Comment: Thank you! If I decide to use SQLiteAssetHelper will I also be able to write on the DB ?

Comment: yup ofc, you can use `getWritableDatabase()` with asset helper to write any values to database

Answer (score 1):

[image]

You have to add it into asset folder and reference it back in helper class

Answer (score 0):

**Put Your Data Base In Asset Folder**

```
  public void CopyDataBaseFromAsset() throws IOException {
    InputStream in  = context.getAssets().open(DATABASE_NAME);
    Log.e("sample", "Starting copying");
    String outputFileName = DATABASE_PATH+DATABASE_NAME;
    File databaseFile = new File( "/data/data/*YOUR PACKGE NAME*/databases");
    // check if databases folder exists, if not create one and its subfolders
    if (!databaseFile.exists()){
        databaseFile.mkdir();
    }

    OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(outputFileName);

    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;


    while ((length = in.read(buffer))>0){
        out.write(buffer,0,length);
    }
    Log.e("sample", "Completed" );
    out.flush();
    out.close();
    in.close();

}
```